# Markdown syntax highlighting in SciTE/Notepad++

Tags: syntax-highlighting, markdown, scite

I'm looking for a `.properties` file for [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics) syntax in [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html). Is it possible?

A partial highlighter would do, otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe somebody mentioned on the mailing list that he is working on such a lexer.
I don't think a simple .properties file can do the job, as there isn't any existing lexer (to my knowledge) with similar syntax.

Answer (score 22):

I'm using this syntax file: https://github.com/leafnode/markdown_npp with some color changes to fit dark background.

Comment: This one worked well for me. Specifically appreciate that he already has multiple configs for a number of the different standard color themes.

Comment: This repo has been taken down now, don't know why, so the link is broken

Answer (score 10):

I've uploaded my (dark) user-defined language [Markdown highlighter on GitHub](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/Notepad---Markdown-Highlighting). It uses different workarounds than thomsmits', which for the style of Markdown I've chosen work better.

Until the Markdown Scintilla lexer is imported into Notepad++, user defined languages are the best we can do.

I don't use Notepad++ any more and have deleted my project. Try Brettz9's fork of the project here: https://github.com/brettz9/Notepad---Markdown-Highlighting

Answer (score 5):

I'm using [Markdown-plus-plus](https://github.com/Edditoria/markdown_npp_zenburn). The install instruction is outdated on many projects. The actual instruction is:

1. Select menu "Language" → "Define your language..."
2. Press button *"Import..."*, and  select {markdown}.xml (from GitHub repositories).
3. Restart Notepad++